# Validate a field contain some regular expression

Tags: validation

Want a regular expression for a field that can accept null value or if value is  provided, the value must start with an alphabetic or numeric character and contains no special character except comma, full stop, '-', ' ' and '_'.
I am using JDK 1.7, Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.